# ant javac print the javac filename

Tags: java, ant

I have an ant build.xml file, and inside it there is a compile target. I often found that when a java file is modified, running the compile target will only re-compile that single java file. On the console, I see

```
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to myproj\.classes
```

But how to ask ant to show which source file it is re-compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `verbose` flag to `true`?

```
<javac ... verbose="true" />
```

Comment: Yes, this does work. It prints more information than I needed, but it does the work. thank you.